# Any angular2 image crop directive available?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Is there any angular2 image crop directive like  [ngImgCrop](https://github.com/alexk111/ngImgCrop)

Comment: Not sure if this question belongs here.

Answer (score 3):

Yes we can use `ng2-img-cropper` component for the same, you just have to install the package named as ng2-img-cropper from the node
using

> npm install ng2-img-cropper --save

than just use the component by importing

`import {ImageCropperComponent, CropperSettings, Bounds} from 'ng2-img-`cropper';

<kbd>[Working plunker here](https://embed.plnkr.co/V91mKCNkBQZB5QO2MUP4/)</kbd>
For more info see here,

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-img-cropper

Comment: Not compiling with current angular version ... Trying to add it to Ionic(2) will emit: ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

Comment: ng2-img-cropper was migrated to latest version of angular 2. Here is the latest working plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/VFwGvAO6MhV06IDTLk5W please check system config file due to the fact that for the cropper only ts files are published

Answer (score 0):

also check this for multiple uploader and cropper using angular typescript
https://github.com/MMtechnolab/Angular-Typescript--2-8-Multiple-Image-Upload-and-Crop-.git Demo :http://mmangimgcrop.gear.host/
I had Also same issue in Angular 8 so i made some changes in ngx-image-cropper, It allows user to upload multiple images as u can see in below image

like this image it allows multiple image selection from your local system

[image: Multiple File Selection]

and crop them by selecting Image Image Cropper

[image: Crop Single File from Selected Image List]

Comment: This library is not compatible with Angular 2, at least I am not able to run it. Any advice?

Comment: Hi there! I managed to make it work! I am using your code, but I changed the library, so it could be compatible with Angular 2. If someone needs help with setting things up, you can text me. ^^

Comment: @Reneta if this answer is useful for you then please mark this answer is useful

Comment: I followed you approach but I did not use the same library, because it was not compatible, that's why I haven't upvote it